# when the Get request is other than Id getting this exception :Failed to convert value of type java.lang.String to required type java.lang.Long

Tags: java, spring-boot

In my SpringBoot code When i make use of Get request for user/{id} is working fine but when use of the request user/modelname.

I'm getting the exception:

> Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type
>   'java.lang.Long';

carController.java

```
@GetMapping("/user/{id}")
    public Car getUser(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return carRepository.findOne(id);
    }

    @GetMapping("/user/modelname")
    public List<Car> searchUserByModel(@RequestBody String modelname) {
        return carRepository.findByModelname(modelname);
    }
```

carRepository.java

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;


public interface CarRepository  extends JpaRepository<Car, Long>{

    public List<Car> findByModelname(String modelname);

}
```

car.java

```
@Entity
public class Car {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String modelname;
public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
public String getModelname() {
        return modelname;
    }

    public void setModelname(String modelname) {
        this.modelname = modelname;
    }

public Car(Long id,String modelname) {
        this.id=id;
        this.modelname = modelname;
    }
@Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Car [id=" + id + ",  modelname=" + modelname +"]";
    }

    public Car() {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your request is not reaching to `@GetMapping("/user/modelname")`. it is always going to `@GetMapping("/user/{id}")` only because it satisfied the condition.
Try changing the url to something else like this `@GetMapping("/users/modelname")` and check ,it will hit definitely.

Comment: Yes exactly how to resolve this. Will the jpaRepository create the findByModelname() method.

Comment: Try changing the url to something else like users . @GetMapping("/users/modelname")

Comment: i have changed to @GetMapping("/users/modelname") ....now if i search like users/s2 getting status 404 data not found

Comment: if you want to pass dynamic modelname then change @GetMapping("/users/modelname")  to @GetMapping("/users/{modelname}").. and do like getUser() method by changing requestbody to pathvariable.